# DB2 use of labeled duration not valid with multiple date intervals

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I'm trying to refactor a MySQL query to run on DB2/iSeries and I'm getting the error Use of labeled duration not valid.

Looking at the documentation I feel like the usage below should be working.

Am I missing something?

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CURDATE() BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS current,
    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CURDATE() -  365 DAY BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS prior,
    IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN '2018-12-31' -  7 DAY BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS full
FROM salesnumbers;
```

Comment: For best results, expiration dates should be an **exclusive** upper-bound (that is, `<`).  This makes querying much simpler overall - In particular, if you're dealing with timestamps it makes it `someTimestamp < TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)`, instead of trying to figure out the maximum.  Unfortunately, `BETWEEN` uses an inclusive bound on both sides, which means it's best avoided for date/time/timestamp types.

Comment: IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN cast( '2018-12-31' as date) -  7 DAY "I didn't see this had answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely your date intervals.  Try using `CURRENT DATE` instead of `CURDATE()`.  Also, you may list date intervals +/- some amount directly in DB2.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CURRENT DATE BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
               THEN 1 END) AS current,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN CURRENT DATE -  1 YEAR BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
               THEN 1 END) AS prior,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE('2018-12-31') - 7 DAY BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
               THEN 1 END) AS full
FROM salesnumbers;
```

Note that I replaced your conditional sums with conditional counts.  This leaves the code slightly more terse, because we don't have to spell out an explicit `ELSE` condition (the default being `NULL`).

Comment: It looks like ```INTERVAL``` is throwing an error and it says that token '1' is not valid. If I remove the ```INTERVAL``` keyword from each line then I get the same labeled duration error

Comment: This is I version 7.2 by the way

Comment: @TomN. Apologies...for whatever reason I initially thought you were trying to go from DB2 to MySQL, not the other way around.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: `@IFNULL()` is superfluous.  `COUNT()` doesn't return `NULL` values.

Comment: `365 DAYS <> 1 YEAR`!  The modification may or may not be correct.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Agreed, but a year, on average, does not have 365 days, it has 365.25 days.  The syntax `1 YEAR` should always mean a year, whereas 365 days might not always mean this.